# Microsoft changed the WIN32_FIND_DATA declaration and added 3 new properties

Tags: winapi

The current microsoft docmentation shows the following declaration for the [WIN32_FIND_DATA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-win32_find_dataa) structure:

```
typedef struct _WIN32_FIND_DATAA {
  DWORD    dwFileAttributes;
  FILETIME ftCreationTime;
  FILETIME ftLastAccessTime;
  FILETIME ftLastWriteTime;
  DWORD    nFileSizeHigh;
  DWORD    nFileSizeLow;
  DWORD    dwReserved0;
  DWORD    dwReserved1;
  CHAR     cFileName[MAX_PATH];
  CHAR     cAlternateFileName[14];
  DWORD    dwFileType;
  DWORD    dwCreatorType;
  WORD     wFinderFlags;
} WIN32_FIND_DATAA, *PWIN32_FIND_DATAA, *LPWIN32_FIND_DATAA;
```

My personal knowledge of the declaration is:

```
typedef struct _WIN32_FIND_DATA {
  DWORD    dwFileAttributes;
  FILETIME ftCreationTime;
  FILETIME ftLastAccessTime;
  FILETIME ftLastWriteTime;
  DWORD    nFileSizeHigh;
  DWORD    nFileSizeLow;
  DWORD    dwReserved0;
  DWORD    dwReserved1;
  TCHAR    cFileName[MAX_PATH];
  TCHAR    cAlternateFileName[14];
} WIN32_FIND_DATA, *PWIN32_FIND_DATA, *LPWIN32_FIND_DATA;
```

Microsoft added these 3 new properties:

```
  DWORD    dwFileType;
  DWORD    dwCreatorType;
  WORD     wFinderFlags;
```

The current Microsoft documentation don't have any description for these properties.

Does anyone have some information about the new properties?

Some other questions:

- Which declaration should a dev use now? The old or new style?
- What about the backward compatibility with older Windows versions?

Comment: this is in conditional block `#ifdef _MAC`

Comment: It's a documentation bug. Trust the header files.